# How to return a JSON object using NodeJS, Passport, mongoose, & MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm new to NodeJS, Passport, and Mongo. I'm trying to set up a basic local authentication, which is successful, however, when I try to return the entire object it returns an empty array.

My node setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose/');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/EiData');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserDetail = new Schema({
      username: String,
      password: String,
  fullname: String
}, {
  collection: 'userlist'
});
var UserDetails = mongoose.model('userlist', UserDetail);

var User_obj = user;

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use( express.cookieParser() );
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'plsrespond' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

So, my tactic is to set a global variable named User_Obj, and set it to be the user object that passport returns. However, I feel like it might be a scope problem, since my global variable is empty when I call it.

Here's my Passport Authentication logic:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    UserDetails.findOne({
      'username': username, 
    }, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }

  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false);
  }

  if (user.password != password) {
    return done(null, false);
  }

  return done(null, user);
});
  });
}));
```

Lastly, my success/failure redirects, and where I attempt to call my User_obj global variable:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
    failureRedirect: '/loginFailure'
  })
);

app.get('/loginFailure', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Invalid code!');
});

app.get('/loginSuccess', function(req, res, next) {

  res.json(User_obj) 
});
```

Comment: Ignoring the decision to use a (somewhat) global variable (will you ever have two users at once?) why are you assigning it to the contents of `./routes/users` - what are you expecting to happen? Where do you assign anything else to `User_obj`? Recommend more time with tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Barry. I may be misunderstanding what passport is doing, and I readily agree that I need more time familiarizing myself with this.

My goal with this is, once the user enters credentials and it validates, return the JSON object of that user. If my approach is wrong, I'd love to know a better approach!

Comment: Not to be unhelpful, but I suggest you spend some time with one or more of the countless tutorials on passport.js that are [all over the web](http://www.bing.com/search?q=nodejs+passport+localstrategy+tutorial). I don't know if the world needs another. Here are some SO user's suggestions for tutorials on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400758/comprehensive-tutorial-for-nodejs-passport-local-strategy-setup)

Comment: I've gone through a couple of those tutorials, namely http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local and http://www.sitepoint.com/local-authentication-using-passport-node-js/ . However, these both redirect to a user profile on success, when I want to render the JSON object for the user. I can see that my global variable approach was incorrect. Perhaps I'm not explaining my situation adequately, I'm sorry.

Comment: Solved it, and I was making a pretty bonehead mistake :P

In order to return the JSON object on login success, I replaced:

    `app.get('/loginSuccess', function(req, res, next) {

      res.json(User_obj) 
    });`

with

    `app.get('/loginSuccess', function(req, res, next) {

      res.send(JSON.stringify(req.user))
    });`


And there was no need for the `User_obj` variable in the first place.

Thanks for bearing with my newb-ness, @barry-johnson :)